# Sequelize: Upsert with returning not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am currently using PostgreSQL 11.4. My attachment table ID is a UUID. Also, it has a unique index on `name, attachableType, attachableId`. I tried using upsert, but it does not return the object as expected:

```
const attachment = await Attachment.upsert(
    {
        name: req.body.name,
        type: 'hidden',
        fileName: req.body.fileName,
        fileUrl: s3path,
        fileType: req.body.fileType,
        fileUpdatedAt: new Date(),
        attachableType: req.body.attachableType,
        attachableId: req.body.attachableId
    },
    {
        returning: true
    }
);
```

`attachment` is `false`. I then tried to use bulkCreate with

```
const [attachment] = await Attachment.bulkCreate(
    [
        {
            name: req.body.name,
            type: 'hidden',
            fileName: req.body.fileName,
            fileUrl: s3path,
            fileType: req.body.fileType,
            fileUpdatedAt: new Date(),
            attachableType: req.body.attachableType,
            attachableId: req.body.attachableId
        }
    ],
    {
        updateOnDuplicate: ['fileUpdatedAt'],
        returning: true
    }
);
```

But I get:

```
Error: postgres does not support the updateOnDuplicate option.
    at Function.bulkCreate (.../node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:2549:29)
    at Function.create (.../catalog/controllers/admin/attachment.js:25:47)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:89:5)
```

Why "postgres does not support the updateOnDuplicate option"? Because I understand postgres does actually support `ON CONFLICT UPDATE`.

Comment: 9 days ago Sequelize developers noticed that PostgreSQL 9.5 is available and finally fixed bulkCreate: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4324

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński, thank you, updated sequelize. But realised it does not take the values returned. For example, the ID returned is the ID it attempted to generate, am using UUID. So reverted to use native query.